# Django application on AWS ECS Fargate keeps restarting after several hours of running successful

Tags: django, gunicorn, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am hosting a Django app on AWS ECS Fargate and I noticed it keeps on restarting after a random number of hours. It runs between 4- 48 hours before restarting. When I check the Event logs of the ECS Task I can see that it is due to health check failure. I have tried everything I know to stop it from restarting, it seems health check failure happens at random after the application has already passed health checks.what can I do to resolve this.

Note: The Django app is not running with Nginx reverse proxy, it uses gunicorn wsgi and whitenoise to serve static files.
The gunicorn uses one worker with the gthread worker type
I also have a similar set on flask but the flask seems to have no issues so I am thinking it’s a Django related issue
The Django app also logs a lot of 404 Not Found errors to the cloud watch logs.
Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: The health checks run constantly You have configured the interval, the endpoint, the required response and the timeout settings. If they are failing after a period of time then you should look to your application log and environment and ask yourself what would stop my application from responding successfully to the health check at that point in time ( memory leak ? insufficient cpu ? are the 404s from the health check requests ? ) . It's not clear how you expect someone here to troubleshoot the inner working of your specific application when Fargate is working as designed.

Comment: @Ronan Cunningham Yes Fargate is working as designed and there are no error logs in the application, I have also checked the memory and cpu and app uses less than 2% of cpu and memory, the 404s aren’t from health check requests, they seem to be coming from somewhere else, the up address points to Russia and the requests are trying to access sensitive information almost like I am being hacked

Comment: Put anything on the internet and you will see that behaviour. I'm afraid I don't have anything else to offer here. I don't know your application nor the health-check settings. If health-checks work but then stop working after a period of time - that can't be diagnosed externally to my mind. You might look at the application logs and see what else is happening when the health checks fail that would cause the application to not be able to respond to the health check within the configured timeout setting and interval.